# Why is plt.imshow (image) only getting output when written in last? How do I show output for all written plt.imshow (image)?

Tags: python-3.x

"Why is plt.imshow (image) only getting output when written in last? How do I show output for all written plt.imshow (image)?I am unable to get all the output where i have used this plt.imshow(image)"

```
import os.path
from skimage.io import imread
from skimage import data_dir
import numpy as np

img=imread(os.path.join(data_dir,'astronaut.png'))
plt.imshow(img)

#1. image slicing from the original image

img_slice=img.copy()
img_slice=img_slice[0:300,360:480]
plt.imshow(img_slice)

img_slice[np.greater_equal(img_slice[:,:,0],100) & np.less_equal(img_slice[:,:,0],150)]=0
plt.imshow(img_slice)

#  Fix the new rocket image back to its place in the original image.
img[0:300,360:480,:]=img_slice
plt.imshow(img)
```

"I am only getting the image for the last written plt.imshow(img). I am unable to get all the images as the output for the written plt.imshow()"

Comment: ```import matplotlib.pyplot as plt    in the code is missed. it is added.

Answer (score 2):

Just add `plt.show()` after your `plt.imshow()` calls!

Also, try to provide the exact same code you are using. Your code snippet doesn't have imports for `plt`.

Anyways, For reference,

```
import os.path
from skimage.io import imread
from skimage import data_dir
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data_dir = '/some/directory/'
img=imread(os.path.join(data_dir,'astronaut.png'))
plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()
#1. image slicing from the original image

img_slice=img.copy()
img_slice=img_slice[0:300,360:480]
plt.imshow(img_slice)
plt.show()

img_slice[np.greater_equal(img_slice[:,:,0],100) & np.less_equal(img_slice[:,:,0],150)]=0
plt.imshow(img_slice)
plt.show()

#  Fix the new rocket image back to its place in the original image.
img[0:300,360:480,:]=img_slice
plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()
```